# date checking issue in javascript function in asp custom validator

Tags: javascript, client-side-validation, customvalidator

I made a simple function for Date Checking and everything seems fine but even if I wrote right date - it gives me that it's wrong

```
unction checkdateClient(source, arguments)

{
    var validformat=/^(\d{2}).(\d{2}).(\d{4})$/

/ //Basic check for format validity which shold be 01.02.2012 


    var returnval=false
    if (!validformat.test(arguments.value))
        arguments.IsValid = false;

    else
    { //Detailed check for valid date ranges
        var monthfield = arguments.value.split(".")[0]
        var dayfield = arguments.value.split(".")[1]
        var yearfield = arguments.value.split(".")[2]
        var dayobj = new Date(yearfield, monthfield-1, dayfield)
        if ((dayobj.getMonth()+1!=monthfield)||(dayobj.getDate()!=dayfield)||(dayobj.getFullYear()!=yearfield))
            arguments.IsValid = false;
        else
            arguments.IsValid = true;
    }

}
```

Comment: is this the actual code?  there appears to be a stray slash

Comment: nitpick: Use semicolons.